# ASP.NET MVC Identity login using database values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, authentication

For the past couple of days I've been trying to get the login functionality working for my ASP.NET MVC application. The user data for my application is stored in a MS SQL database (2008 R2). The table for this data is as follows:

```
table EMPLOYEE
EMPLOYEECODE        int                  identity
NAME                varchar(75)          not null
PASSWORD            varchar(255)         not null
```

Which results in the following model using the Entity Framework:

```
public partial class EMPLOYEE
{    
    public int EMPLOYEECODE { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do, is edit the provided (default) AccountController to enable it to use EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEECODE, PASSWORD) to verify and login users. I think I need to alter my UserManager to make it use EMPLOYEE and the fields EMPLOYEECODE and PASSWORD but I don't know how. The current login method is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
           ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

My UserManager is instanciated as follows:

```
public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {
    }
```

How could I solve this problem? I have also tried using an authentication cookie, but I don't know how I can retrieve the username from the cookie. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The UserManager and UserStore are associated with the ASP.NET Identity authentication with its own tables for users, roles, etc... If you want to use different tables you have to create a custom login functionality.

Comment: Would this be possible using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username) if the credentials match with the credentials in the Database? If so, how could I decrypt the authentication to check which user matches the authentication cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar request and what I ended up doing was the following:

- Used migrations to create the Identity tables
- Modified the Identity classes to use and INT instead of GUID as the Id
- Migrated my data from the Employee table to the AspNetUsers table
- In your case, map the EmployeeCode to the AspNetUsers.Id field and the password to the AspNetUsers.PasswordHash.
- Depending on how your passwords are saved in the Db, you might need to add an extra step here to get them into the table in a hashed format.

If your passwords need to be hashed, instead of migration the data, take a look at how users are registered in Identity and put your existing users through the same process like so:

1. Get a list of all the users in your Employee table
2. For each user, use the owin context to retrive the UserManager and SignIn Manager
3. Create a new ApplicationUser using the EmployeeCode and EmployeePassword
4. Use the UserManager to create the user in the Database